# R - putting in string in new empty column based on string text in another column

Tags: r

I am struggling with this on R. Looking to create a new column based with with string values based on string from another column. I was able to create an empty column but I am confused about how to create new strings based on a column which has other strings. if data in column 1 called bank is jpm, cs, gs, bmo etc then i want to be able to put say north america in an empty column 4 for all instances of jpm and put in say switzerland for all instances of cs. Thanks for your help

Eg:

```
Banks           New column
JPM             North America
CS              Switzerland
JPM             North America
GS
CS              Switzerland
BMO
CS              Switzerland
```

Comment: Try looking at the `ifelse` command in R as well as the `%in%` operator. A simplified example might be: `ifelse(Banks %in% "JPM", "North America","")`

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1088/creating-vectors/10854/creating-named-vectors) describing named vectors in SO Documentation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to have a mapping table, and then merge with the old data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Banks = c("JPM", "CS", "GS"), New_Col = c("North America", "Switzerland", ""))
res <- merge(df_old, df, by = "Banks", all.x = T)
```

Comment: Alternately, adding the column in place, like `df_old$col <- df$new[match(df_old$Banks, df$Banks)]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
df <-read.table(text="Banks
JPM
CS
JPM
GS
CS
BMO
CS",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df%>%
mutate(New_column=case_when(
.$Banks %in% c("JPM","BMO","GS") ~ "North America",
.$Banks %in% c("CS")             ~ "Switzerland"
))

  Banks    New_column
1   JPM North America
2    CS   Switzerland
3   JPM North America
4    GS North America
5    CS   Switzerland
6   BMO North America
7    CS   Switzerland
```

Comment: No need to use `.$Banks`, simply `Banks` is ok in the `mutate()` call.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I just checked. Your suggestion works in the devel version of dplyr (0.6.0). I'll leave it like this in the moment as it doesn't work in 0.5.0.